# Python profiling: KCacheGrind + Yappi keeps displaying an unknown function

Tags: python, profiler, kcachegrind, yappi

I want to profile my Python program to understand why it is so slow. I decided to use Yappi - because my program is multithreaded - and to diplay the results with KCacheGrind. Here is how I do it:

```
# Profile of the update method
def profile_update(table, start, end):
    print("Profiling update() on the %s table..." % (table))
    yappi.start(builtins=True)
    app.update(...)
    stats = yappi.get_func_stats()
    output_name = "profiler_%s.out." % (table) + datetime.now().isoformat()
    stats.save("profilers_outputs/" + output_name, type='callgrind')
    yappi.stop()
    yappi.clear_stats()
    print('\n\n\n')
```

The method update is used to fetch data from a database with a time range between start and end.

The output file is correctly created but when I launch KCacheGrind it prints a lot of errors like this:

```
kcachegrind(35484): Loading "profilers_outputs/profiler_benchmark.out.2019-06-26T17:21:41.147461" : 17529 :  "Undefined compressed function index 586"
kcachegrind(35484): Loading "profilers_outputs/profiler_benchmark.out.2019-06-26T17:21:41.147461" : 17529 :  "Invalid called function, setting to unknown"
```

I end up with this [call graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axnl0.jpg) where all the non recognized functions are aggregated as one, making it messy and completely irrelevant. Does anyone know why it is happening ?

Comment: Can you share the stats themselves (i.e. the contents of the stats file)?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but that was 4 months ago, I don't have the data anymore. And even back then I was not allowed to share it.

Comment: Damn, now I'm curious as to what happened. Welp - if it ever comes up again, LMK 

Answer (score 0):

This issue is now resolved in Yappi. Take a look at this github [pull request](https://github.com/sumerc/yappi/pull/150) and [issue](https://github.com/sumerc/yappi/issues/95).

The version containing this fix: [v1.5.1](https://github.com/sumerc/yappi/releases/tag/v1.5.1)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).